# Save twitter Oauthtoken and secret token for user profile?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have a web app that lets users sign in their twitter account. It also creates a user profile on my database as well and I need save their tokens so I'd have a unique Id. I plan to one way encrypt the tokens like passwords for security sake. My question is do I need to save the pair or just one of them will suffice as a unique Id?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use their Twitter user id? It's unique

Comment: Oh! thanks! Hadn't thought of that. Hope it's unique enough to not overlap with other users who register the regular way.

Comment: They're numeric so if you want to make sure there's no clashes, add a non-numeric character or 2 into your unique ids